# Automatically resize DockWidgets to same heights after adding a new DockWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qdockwidget

I'm currently writing a small application, that allows the user to freely define plots. The current solution uses `QDockWidget`, so that the user can resize and rearrange the plots as he pleases.

I'm quite happy with this solution, but there is still a drawback. In case the user adds a new `QDockWidget` to the already defined ones a good behavior would be to resize all `QDockWidget`s to have the same heights.

The following code illustrates what I'm trying to achieve.

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDockWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QAction>
#include <QMenuBar>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    auto window = new QMainWindow;
    auto label = new QLabel("Central Widget");
    label->hide();
    window->setCentralWidget(label);
    window->setDockNestingEnabled(true);
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        auto dock = new QDockWidget(QString("Plot %1").arg(i));
        dock->setWidget(new QLabel(QString("Plot %1").arg(i)));
        window->addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, dock);
    }
    window->setFixedSize(QSize(300, 600));
    window->show();

    // User presses a button and the following would get executed!
    auto dock = new QDockWidget(QString("New Plot"));
    dock->setWidget(new QLabel(QString("New Plot")));
    window->addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, dock);
    return app.exec();
}
```

Unfortunately, the newly added plot has a very small size, whereas the other two are still large.

[image: Behavior of code]

The desired behavior should be something like this, after I manually resized the dock widgets.
[image: Desired behavior]

How can I achieve this behavior with the least amount of extra work? Do I really have to resize all my QDockWidgets manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you have not defined any minimum size to the `QDockWidgets`. So if you want your third dock widget should be of the same size. Set its minimum height to the 1/3rd of the total window size like this:

```
dock->setMinimumHeight(window->height()/3); //! This is the third dock widget
```

Comment: What if he has more than 3 `QDockWidget`s?

Comment: @IAmInPLS I mean to say Frank added initially two DockWidgets and called `window->show()` so `window` resize the available `dockwidgets` according to the available size. So when third `dockwidget` added and dockwidget doesn't have any minimum size so it will not resize other dockwidgets which is why complete window area not get shared between them. Three is just an example there can be `n dockwidgets`.

Comment: My company uses Qt 5.5. I figured out by accident that the `QMainWindow` class in Qt 5.6 has the function `QMainWindow::resizeDocks(const QList<QDockWidget *> &docks, const QList<int> &sizes, Qt::Orientation orientation)`. I think I need something equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing in my Docking system by using a new function that came with Qt 5.6 (intended exactly for this use case):

```
void QMainWindow::resizeDocks(const QList<QDockWidget *> &docks, 
                              const QList<int> &sizes, 
                              Qt::Orientation orientation)
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#resizeDocks

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the hint. Actually, I found this function already. See comment above. But unfortunately I have to rely on Qt 5.5.